# ¿Cómo hacer que una imagen utilizada como background mantenga un tamaño de altura fijo al ser responsive?

Tags: html, responsive

Estoy utilizando un imagen estilo banner para la página de búsqueda en la cual esta imagen la coloco de fondo detrás del buscados unos títulos y el botón. Al ejecutar el código la imagen tiene un alto el cual me gustaría replicar ese mismo alto en diferentes dispositivos como móviles y/o tablets.

Al testear su desempeño responsive el alto de la imagen se expande mucho lo cual es todo lo contrario que quiero.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que la imagen tenga un alto fijo al adaptarse en las diferentes pantallas y evitar que se expanda?

Estuve testeando con lo min y max height y también con los @media pero no conseguí el resultado deseado.

**Este es el tamaño que me gustaría mantener de la imagen de fondo**
[image: ar]

**Se estira demasiado y me gustaría que mantenga más o menos las dimensiones de los rectángulos rojos tratando de mantener el estilo de la imagen de arriba**
[image: da]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #141414;
}


/* ------------- SCROLLBAR ------------- */

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 6.5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}


/* ------------- ELIMINAR SUBRAYADO ------------- */

a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.grid-container>* {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #232d35;
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template: "header" 70px "main" auto "navbar" 50px "footer" 100px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template: "navbar header" 65px "main  main" auto "footer  footer" 100px / 200px auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template: "navbar  header  header" 55px "main    main    main" auto "footer  footer  footer" 100px / 200px auto 200px;
  }
}


/* -----------------  ENCABEZADO  ----------------- */

.header {
  padding-top: 1.2%;
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #4c5672;
  border-left: 2.5px solid #EEE7CE;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #EEE7CE;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.header .logo {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 1.35rem;
  font-weight: 450;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header .logo i {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: #b884c4;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
}

.header .logoLupa {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-left: 55%;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.header .logoHeart {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-left: 3%;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  margin-top: -.3%;
}

.header .icons div,
.header .icons a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline;
}

.header .icons div:hover,
.header .icons a:hover {
  color: #c228ff;
}

.header .menu-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 170%;
  margin-top: -15%;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: transparent;
}

.header .right-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* -----------------  CONTENIDO  PÁGINA  ----------------- */

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #0f1214;
}

.main .row3 {
  background: url(https://www.medecs.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Banner-970x250-1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  /* posiciono al centro la imagen para que no se desborde */
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  /* background-size: 100%; */
  /* quito el ancho del 100% que tenía */
  min-height: 55vh;
  max-height: 55vh;
  border-bottom: #EEE7CE 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.row3 .btn {
  margin-top: 3.25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: .80rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: .65rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #558486;
  border: 1.5px solid #00000000;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 550;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.input-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 76px;
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.input-box i,
.input-box .button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.input-box i {
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #707070;
}

.input-box input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 155px 0 65px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.input-box .button {
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #785586;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input-box .button.clicked {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.98);
}


/* Responsive BUSCADOR */

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .input-box {
    height: 66px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  .input-box i {
    left: 12px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .input-box input {
    padding: 0 112px 0 50px;
  }
  .input-box .button {
    right: 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px 18px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 765px) {
  .main .row3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .main .row3 .btn {
    font-size: 0.8rem !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSearchBox.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
</head>

<body class="grid-container">
  <!----------- ENCABEZADO ----------->
  <header class="header">
    <a href="/" class="logo"> <i class="uil uil-book-alt"></i> Biblioteca</a>


    <!-- <a href="/exploreBooksPublic" class="logoLupa"> <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>

        <a href="#" class="logoHeart"> <i class="uil uil-heart"></i></a>

        <div class="loggedin">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="right-menu">
                    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="/login" role="button">Acceder</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> -->
  </header>
  <!----------- CONTENIDO PRINCIPAL ----------->
  <article class="main">
    <div class="row3">
      <div class="content">
        <h3 style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></h3><br></br>
      </div>
      <form action="/buscarLibro" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column m-4" method='post' style="margin-top: 3%;">
        <div class="input-box mb-4">
          <i class="uil uil-search"></i>
          <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar libro..." />
          <button type="submit" class="button">Buscar</button>
        </div>
        <span style="color: rgb(233, 233, 233); font-size: medium;">Títulos - Autores - Editoriales - IESBN</span>
      </form>
      <a href="/registrarLibros" class="btn btn-link">
        <i class="uil uil-book-alt"></i> Registrar Libro
      </a>
    </div>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ayudaría si dejaras un ejemplo de como querés que se vea en diferentes pantallas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que la imagen tenga un alto fijo y no se expanda en diferentes dispositivos, puedes utilizar la propiedad "background-size" y establecer el valor en "contain". Esto permitirá que la imagen se ajuste al tamaño de la pantalla sin expandirse.

Además, en lugar de usar "min-height" y "max-height" para establecer el alto de la imagen, puedes utilizar "height" y establecer un valor fijo en píxeles. De esta forma, la imagen tendrá siempre el mismo alto independientemente del tamaño de la pantalla.

Aquí te muestro cómo podrías modificar el estilo de tu clase ".main .row3":

```
.main .row3 {
  background: url(https://www.medecs.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Banner-970x250-1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 400px; /* Estableces un valor fijo en píxeles */
  border-bottom: #EEE7CE 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Recuerda que al establecer un valor fijo para el alto de la imagen, esta no será responsive y podría no verse bien en algunos dispositivos. Para solucionarlo, puedes utilizar media queries y establecer diferentes valores de alto para diferentes tamaños de pantalla.

Comment: Buena respuesta, creo que lo más importante es la parte de darle una altura al elemento y `background-size: cover` también puede ser una buena idea. Ya que `contain` solo permite que la imagen se agrande para cubrir todo el espacio del elemento sin que sufra recortes.